# Chaining Continuation call forImported wsdl

Tags: visualforce, soap-api, continuation

I have developed a VF page which needs to do 3 call outs to external system in a sequence. The wsdl has been shared for these web services. We have implemented the continuation pattern based for wsdl call out as per the [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_continuation_callout_soap.htm). However I am not able to chain them. I could chain it using on complete on action function to chain the calls but it requires a round trip back to the browser which i wish to avoid.
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the process response method of first callout you have to make second Callout Continuation instance.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_continuation_chained_callouts.htm